# Add ContextMenu to usercontrols in WrapPanel

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, binding, contextmenu, datacontext

I've got a WrapPanel from the Silverlight Toolkit in a WP7 application. In my codebehind I add my own usercontrols to this wrappanel. Each usercontrol is a square that displays information about a flight.

```
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="307" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <toolkit:WrapPanel x:Name="MonitoredWrapPanel" Margin="10,0,0,0" MinWidth="200" Width="{Binding ElementName=MyScrollViewer, Path=ViewportWidth}">
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="FlightContextMenuInGrid">
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Stop monitoring flight" Click="MenuItem_Click" Tag="{Binding Path=FlightId}" />
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:WrapPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

And the codebehind;

```
        foreach (var flight in Cache.MonitoredCombinedFlights)
        {
            FlightSquare square = new FlightSquare();
            square.DataContext = flight;
            square.Margin = new Thickness(10, 5, 10, 5);
            this.MonitoredWrapPanel.Children.Add(square);
        }
```

My problem is that the MenuItem (for the ContextMenu) doesn't bind to the FlightId property of the DataContext for my User Control, instead it just binds to itself.

How can I get the MenuItem to understand which FlightSquare it is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `ContextMenu` has a different `DataContext`. Binding in each square has nothing to do with the `WrapPanel` here and you will have to manually set the binding object for the `ContextMenu` in the code-behind.

So to say, here is a snippet that shows how you can bind to a property in code-behind (exactly what you need to do):

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = ObjectToBindTo;
b.Path = new PropertyPath("PropertyToBindTo");

menu.SetBinding(DependencyPropertyToBind, b);
```

That being said, there is one more problem in your case. The `ContextMenu` is inside a `WrapPanel` - it is tied to it and not to the square. Therefore, you might change the way you are using the `ContextMenu` to be inside the square instance rather than the common container.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer Dennis, here is what I ended up with. I'm using a listbox in combination with the wrappanel to be able scroll the list of squares.

```
<ListBox Height="311" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,323,0,0" Name="MonitoredCombinedFlightsList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel x:Name="MonitoredWrapPanel" Margin="10,0,0,0" MinWidth="200">
                    </toolkit:WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Views:FlightSquare Margin="10,5,10,5">
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="FlightContextMenuInGrid">
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Stop monitoring flight" Click="MenuItem_Click" Tag="{Binding Path=FlightId}" />
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    </Views:FlightSquare>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

and in my codebehind;

```
MonitoredCombinedFlightsList.ItemsSource = Cache.MonitoredCombinedFlights;
```